# GitHub Markdown link containing parentheses

Tags: markdown

The following does not work:

```
[using Leksah](#Leksah-(setup-difficulty-hard))
```

nor this:

```
[using Leksah](#Leksah-\(setup-difficulty-hard\))
```

and neither this:

```
[using Leksah](#Leksah-%28setup-difficulty-hard%29)
```

How can I write a GitHub Markdown link containing parentheses?

See example not working links [here](https://github.com/razvan-flavius-panda/haskell-editor-setup/tree/9426d09ec59fe74aabbde666a3d058954963e9c0#install-the-editor--ide-of-your-choice)

Answer (score 5):

The link would work as you first tried it, but the auto-generated id of the header you're trying to link to has the braces stripped. Use:

```
[using Leksah](#leksah-setup-difficulty-hard)
```

Comment: This one worked beautifully. As you said, we have to pretend as if parentheses do not exist at all. So, If you want to link something like `amir(1)` use something like `#amir1`. Also, see [this](https://github.com/alshedivat/al-folio/pull/876/files) one as an example.